# Change thickness of TikZ pattern library patterns

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [custom and built in tikz fill patterns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54358/custom-and-built-in-tikz-fill-patterns)

Is it possible to change the thickness of patterns drawn by the TikZ pattern library (IV Libraries, 41 Pattern Library)? Setting `thick` on the node, only applies to the node itself, not the filling pattern.

```
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[square,thick,pattern={north east lines}] {}; % draws a thick square with a thin pattern
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: AFAIK the patterns are not key-aware... So you will need to define your own pattern or modify the code in `pgflibrarypatterns.code.tex`.

Comment: Yeah, I think @CountZero is right, you won't get around defining a new pattern for this. For the `north east lines` pattern, however, you're in luck: At http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29367/2552 there's a new version of the pattern which allows changing the line width and the distance between the lines using keys.

Comment: Also related : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54358/custom-and-built-in-tikz-fill-patterns