# Pgfplots and beamer: how to fill the area under a curve with oblique lines (hatching) as a pattern?

Tags: beamer, pgfplots

This is a follow up question to [Jake's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29367/3690)  to that post.

Although I got [Jake's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29367/3690) there work in LaTeX document perfectly fine, I could not get it work in `beamer`. Here's Jake's code but using `beamer`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{
        hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
        hatch distance=10pt,
        hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
        hatch thickness=2pt
    }

    \makeatletter
    \pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{flexible hatch}
    {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    {\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
    {\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
    {
        \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }

    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-4,xmax=4,
        xlabel={z},
        ymin=0,ymax=1,
        axis on top,
        legend style={legend cell align=right,legend plot pos=right}] 
    \addplot[color=red,domain=-4:4,samples=100] {1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-x^2/2)};
    \addlegendentry{z}
    \addplot+[mark=none,
        domain=0:1,
        samples=100,
        pattern=flexible hatch,
        area legend,
        pattern color=red]{1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-x^2/2)} \closedcycle;
    \addlegendentry{Interval 1}
    \addplot+[mark=none,
        domain=-2:-0.5,
        samples=100,
        pattern=flexible hatch,
        hatch distance=5pt,
        hatch thickness=0.5pt,
        draw=blue,
        pattern color=cyan,
        area legend]{1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-x^2/2)} \closedcycle;    
        \addlegendentry{Interval 2}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It seems the system never finish compiling. I not sure whether it is just my system or it is a more general problem?

Meanwhile, [Marco's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29361/3690) there does work in `beamer`.

Comment: Please compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: I've added to your question the example code illustrating the problem; I hope it's OK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply add the `fragile` option to the frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{
        hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
        hatch distance=10pt,
        hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
        hatch thickness=2pt
    }

    \makeatletter
    \pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{flexible hatch}
    {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    {\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
    {\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
    {
        \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }

    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-4,xmax=4,
        xlabel={z},
        ymin=0,ymax=1,
        axis on top,
        legend style={legend cell align=right,legend plot pos=right}] 
    \addplot[color=red,domain=-4:4,samples=100] {1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-x^2/2)};
    \addlegendentry{z}
    \addplot+[mark=none,
        domain=0:1,
        samples=100,
        pattern=flexible hatch,
        area legend,
        pattern color=red]{1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-x^2/2)} \closedcycle;
    \addlegendentry{Interval 1}
    \addplot+[mark=none,
        domain=-2:-0.5,
        samples=100,
        pattern=flexible hatch,
        hatch distance=5pt,
        hatch thickness=0.5pt,
        draw=blue,
        pattern color=cyan,
        area legend]{1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-x^2/2)} \closedcycle;    
        \addlegendentry{Interval 2}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Add `[fragile]` after `\begin{frame}[fragile]`  It is common for LaTeX-Tikz to hang when code is involved and [fragile] it is omitted.