# pgfplots -- Patterns are not displaying correctly in PDF version 1.4

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pdftex, pdf

I am using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29359/pgfplots-how-to-fill-the-area-under-a-curve-with-oblique-lines-hatching-as-a) method to plot a pattern in-between two curves. If I save the file as PDF version 1.5 everything looks great. Unfortunately the journal that I am submitting the paper to requires PDF version 1.4. When I use pdflatex and generate a PDF 1.4 file (or use gs to convert it afterwards), the pattern goes outside the bounds of the lines. Is there any work around to this?

[image: Good]

[image: Bad]

Comment: When editing your question, you can add images using the [Image]-Button just over the text area.

Comment: Is this related to pgfplots? Or does it happen with a plain tikz picture and such a pattern as well?

Comment: This seems to be only a problem with the viewer. The screenshots above were taken from 'evince'. Once I opened the file in Adobe Acrobat, everything was fine. If a moderator wants to mark this question as closed that is fine with me.

Comment: Ok. I also observed drawing issues for patterns/shadings in evince. Apparently, it is a little bit buggy.