# How to color parts of a plan in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following figure:
[image]

The place where I added captions like red, blue or green I want those areas of the plan filled with the color of the captions. 
How do I do it.

In case you need the code for what I have done so far is here:

```
\documentclass{article} % say
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \definecolor{colorforline}{RGB}{49,4,71};
        \definecolor{shade}{RGB}{156, 166, 176};
        \draw [very thick, color=colorforline] (-5,0) -- (5,0) node[] {};
        \draw [very thick, color=colorforline] (-5,0) -- (-5,6) node[] {};
        \draw [very thick,color=colorforline] plot [smooth] coordinates { (-5,0) (-3,1) (0,5) (3,1) (5,0) };
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Partition of sample space $S$ associated with a discrete random variable.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here is what I really want:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pgfplots: how to fill the area under a curve with oblique lines (hatching) as a pattern?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29359/pgfplots-how-to-fill-the-area-under-a-curve-with-oblique-lines-hatching-as-a)

Comment: @MikeRenfro This does require switching to `pgfplots`, of course. I don't think the question can be considered a duplicate for that reason. (But it will now, presumably, get closed as one.) The issue is whether the question is a duplicate - not whether the answer might be.

Comment: Certainly. I assumed this was for a Gaussian distribution, and if so, having the real equation would be useful. And I can certainly retract my (the only) close vote.

Comment: Please see the update question. I have added a figure in the end, that is what I want

Comment: Why you call it a *plan*?

Comment: maybe I am bad at math, that's why. what is it by the way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-4,xmax=4,
        ymin=0,ymax=0.5,
        axis on top,
        axis y line*=left,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        xlabel = {Total Points},
        xtick={4},
        xticklabels={Maximum Possible},
        ytick={0},
        yticklabels={},
        ylabel = {Relative Frequency}]
    \addplot[color=black,domain=-4:4,samples=100] {1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-x^2/2)};
    \addplot+[mark=none,
      domain=-4:-2,
      samples=100,
      fill=red,
      draw=black,
      area legend]{1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-x^2/2)} \closedcycle; 
    \addplot+[mark=none,
      domain=-2:1,
      samples=100,
      fill=yellow,
      draw=black,
      area legend]{1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-x^2/2)} \closedcycle; 
    \addplot+[mark=none,
      domain=1:2,
      samples=100,
      fill=cyan,
      draw=black,
      area legend]{1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-x^2/2)} \closedcycle; 
    \addplot+[mark=none,
      domain=2:4,
      samples=100,
      fill=green,
      draw=black,
      area legend]{1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-x^2/2)} \closedcycle; 
    \node[above] at (axis cs:-3,0.05) {D or F}; 
    \node[above] at (axis cs:-0.5,0.05) {C}; 
    \node[above] at (axis cs:1.5,0.05) {B}; 
    \node[above] at (axis cs:3,0.05) {A}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i appreciate your help but I don't want the numbers and the dashes on the line

Comment: @Saad Add `xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty` to the `axis` options (and possibly `axis lines=left` if you only want lines on the left and bottom).

Comment: @Saad updated answer.