# How to make this free body diagram with a non-straight force line using tikzpicture environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Please consider the following MWE adapted from [this fantastic example of Kjell Magne Fauske's free body diagram](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/free-body-diagrams/):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}           % From http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/free-body-diagrams/
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}
\begin{document}

\def\iangle{0} % Angle of the inclined plane

\def\down{-90}
\def\arcr{0.5cm} % Radius of the arc used to indicate angles

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=4,
    force/.style={->,draw=blue,fill=blue},
    axis/.style={densely dashed,gray,font=\small},
    M/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=lightgray,minimum size=0.5cm,thin},
    m/.style={rectangle,draw=black,fill=lightgray,minimum size=0.3cm,thin},
    plane/.style={draw=black,fill=blue!10},
    string/.style={draw=red, thick},
    pulley/.style={thick},
]

    %% Free body diagram of M
    \begin{scope}[rotate=\iangle]
        \node[M,transform shape] (M) {};
        % Draw axes and help lines

        {[axis,->]
            \draw (0,-1) -- (0,2) node[right] {$+y$};
            \draw (M) -- ++(2,0) node[right] {$+x$};    % mental note for me: change "right" to "above"
        }

        % Forces
        {[force,->]
            % Assuming that Mg = 1. The normal force will therefore be cos(alpha)
            \draw (M.center) -- ++(0,{cos(\iangle)}) node[above right] {$\vec N$};
            \draw (M.west) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$\vec f_r$};
        }

    \end{scope}
    % Draw gravity force. The code is put outside the rotated
    % scope for simplicity. No need to do any angle calculations. 
    \draw[force,->] (M.center) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\vec P$};
    %%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example of body free diagram]

With your huge help, I would like to know how to

1. add a line with slope (e.g. with an inclination of `53º` <- with the label and the correct slope). *Note that the source already has a code for the angle*, it may be the same in this case;
2. make proportional axis and not "from wherever you are, go above/right by `2`", e.g. a `30 ~ 40%` more long than the length of the force lines (I ask this because if `scale=4` then the axis lines are too large than the force lines);
3. aditionally add a "floor" with black diagonal lines (maybe [this Milo's excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445706/152550) or [this marmot's awesome response](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445707/152550) helps?);
4. the friction force line `f_r` in front of the body and not behind;
5. the possibility of descompose the forces that are not horizontal/vertical (maybe with the same style of the axis line, idk, be creative with format!).

I want something like this:

[image: What I want]

If possible, I would like you to keep the code format of the MWE so that I do not have to adapt to another code style, but add to the current one.

If you think that the colors are monotonous you can propose darker grays or other styles!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My humble attempt using `arrows` (which got superseded by `arrows.meta`; see below for a version using that library), `decoration.markings` and `angles` libraries.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings,angles}

\def\Fangle{53}
\def\Flength{5}
\def\iangle{20}
\def\Plength{2}
\def\Gwidth{5}
\def\Gthick{3pt}
\def\Gstep{4pt}
\def\coordwd{1}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    ,force/.style={>=latex',->,draw=blue,fill=blue}
    ,force component/.style={>=latex',->,draw=gray,fill=gray}
    ,M/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=lightgray,minimum size=0.5cm,thin}
    ,note/.style={font=\small}
    ,ground/.style={black,postaction={ground hatch}}
    ,ground hatch/.style=
      {
        decorate,
        decoration=
          {
            ,markings
            ,mark =
              between positions 0 and 1 step \Gstep
              with{\draw[darkgray] (-\Gthick,-\Gthick) -- (0,0);}
          }
      }
    ,my angles/.style=
      {
        ,draw=green!70!black
        ,->
        ,angle radius=9mm
        ,angle eccentricity=1.3
        ,pic text=#1
        ,font = \small
      }
    ,coord/.style={dashed,gray,>=latex',->,transform shape}
  ]
  \begin{scope}[rotate=\iangle]
    \node[M,transform shape] (M) {};
    \draw[force] (M.center) ++(\Fangle+90:\Flength) coordinate (F)
      --node[at start,above left,note]{$\vec{F}$} (M.center);
    \draw[force component] (F)
      --node[at end,above left,gray,note,transform shape,rotate=-90]
        {$\Vert\vec{F}\Vert\cos\SI{\Fangle}{\degree}$}
      (F|-M.center) coordinate (fr);
    \draw[force component] (F) 
      --node[at end,above left,gray,note,transform shape]
        {$\Vert\vec{F}\Vert\sin\SI{\Fangle}{\degree}$}
      (F-|M.center) coordinate (N);
    \draw[force] (M.center)
      --node[at end,below,note]{$\vec{f}_r$} (fr);
    \draw[force] (M.center)
      --node[at end,right,note]{$\vec{N}$} (N);
    \draw[ground] (M.south) ++(-\Gwidth/2,0) -- ++(\Gwidth,0) coordinate (G);
    \path (M.center) coordinate (Mc)
      pic[my angles=\SI\Fangle\degree]
      {angle=N--Mc--F};
    \draw[coord] (N) --node[at end,above]{$+y$} ++(0,\coordwd);
    \draw[coord] (M.east) --node[at end,right]{$+x$} ++(\coordwd,0);
  \end{scope}
  \draw[force] (M.center) --node[at end,below,note]{$\vec{P}$} ++(0,-\Plength);
  \draw[dashed,darkgray] (M.south) -- ++(2,0) coordinate (H);
  \path (M.south) coordinate (Ms)
    pic[my angles=\SI\iangle\degree]
    {angle=H--Ms--G};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing the 53° label to the position you want, also using `arrows.meta` instead of `arrows`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings,angles}

\def\Fangle{53}
\def\Flength{5}
\def\iangle{20}
\def\Plength{2}
\def\Gwidth{5}
\def\Gthick{3pt}
\def\Gstep{4pt}
\def\coordwd{1}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    ,force/.style={>=Stealth,->,draw=blue,fill=blue}
    ,force component/.style={>=Stealth,->,draw=gray,fill=gray}
    ,M/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=lightgray,minimum size=0.5cm,thin}
    ,note/.style={font=\small}
    ,ground/.style={black,postaction={ground hatch}}
    ,ground hatch/.style=
      {
        decorate,
        decoration=
          {
            ,markings
            ,mark =
              between positions 0 and 1 step \Gstep
              with{\draw[darkgray] (-\Gthick,-\Gthick) -- (0,0);}
          }
      }
    ,my angles/.style=
      {
        ,draw=green!70!black
        ,->
        ,angle radius=9mm
        ,angle eccentricity=1.3
        ,pic text=#1
        ,font = \small
      }
    ,coord/.style={dashed,gray,>=Stealth,->,transform shape}
  ]
  \begin{scope}[rotate=\iangle]
    \node[M,transform shape] (M) {};
    \draw[force] (M.center) ++(\Fangle+90:\Flength) coordinate (F)
      --node[at start,above left,note]{$\vec{F}$} (M.center);
    \draw[force component] (F)
      --node[at end,above left,gray,note,transform shape,rotate=-90]
        {$\Vert\vec{F}\Vert\cos\SI{\Fangle}{\degree}$}
      (F|-M.center) coordinate (fr);
    \draw[force component] (F) 
      --node[at end,above left,gray,note,transform shape]
        {$\Vert\vec{F}\Vert\sin\SI{\Fangle}{\degree}$}
      (F-|M.center) coordinate (N);
    \draw[force] (M.center)
      --node[at end,below,note]{$\vec{f}_r$} (fr);
    \draw[force] (M.center)
      --node[at end,right,note]{$\vec{N}$} (N);
    \draw[ground] (M.south) ++(-\Gwidth/2,0) -- ++(\Gwidth,0) coordinate (G);
    \path (M.center) coordinate (Mc)
      pic[my angles=\SI\Fangle\degree]
      {angle=fr--F--Mc};
    \draw[coord] (N) --node[at end,above]{$+y$} ++(0,\coordwd);
    \draw[coord] (M.east) --node[at end,right]{$+x$} ++(\coordwd,0);
  \end{scope}
  \draw[force] (M.center) --node[at end,below,note]{$\vec{P}$} ++(0,-\Plength);
  \draw[dashed,darkgray] (M.south) -- ++(2,0) coordinate (H);
  \path (M.south) coordinate (Ms)
    pic[my angles=\SI\iangle\degree]
    {angle=H--Ms--G};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also, in this particular graph I would like to draw the `53º` label with respect the left vertical, not the right (like my picture). Btw I think this is an excellent answer!

Comment: i.e. [something like this](https://imgur.com/a/lyhEWED).

Answer (score 6):

Here is my attempt

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
    calc,
    decorations,
    scopes,
}

\begin{document}
    \def\iangle{20} % Angle of the inclined plane

    \def\down{-90}
    \def\arcr{0.5cm} % Radius of the arc used to indicate angles

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        >=latex',
        scale=1,
        force/.style={->,draw=blue,fill=blue},
        axis/.style={densely dashed,gray,font=\small},
        M/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=lightgray,minimum size=0.5cm,thin},
        m/.style={rectangle,draw=black,fill=lightgray,minimum size=0.3cm,thin},
        plane/.style={draw=black,fill=blue!10},
        string/.style={draw=red, thick},
        pulley/.style={thick},
        ]
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Fnorme}{2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Fangle}{30}
        \begin{scope}[rotate=\iangle]
            \node[M,transform shape] (M) {};
            \coordinate (xmin) at ($(M.south west)-({abs(1.1*\Fnorme*sin(-\Fangle))},0)$);
            \coordinate (xmax) at ($(M.south east)+({abs(1.1*\Fnorme*sin(-\Fangle))},0)$);
            \coordinate (ymax) at ($(M.north)+(0, {abs(1.1*\Fnorme*cos(-\Fangle))})$);
            \coordinate (ymin) at ($(M.south)-(0, 1cm)$);
            \draw[postaction={decorate, decoration={border, segment length=2pt, angle=-45},draw,red}] (xmin) -- (xmax);
            \coordinate (N) at ($(M.center)+(0,{\Fnorme*cos(-\Fangle)})$);
            \coordinate (fr) at ($(M.center)+({\Fnorme*sin(-\Fangle)}, 0)$);
            % Draw axes and help lines

            {[axis,->]
                \draw (ymin) -- (ymax) node[right] {$+y$};
                \draw (M) --(M-|xmax) node[right] {$+x$};    % mental note for me: change "right" to "above"
            }

            % Forces
            {[force,->]
                \draw [<-] (M.center) -- (90+\Fangle:\Fnorme cm) node [anchor=east]{$\vec F$};
                % Assuming that Mg = 1. The normal force will therefore be cos(alpha)
                \draw (M.center) -- (N) node [right] {$\vec N$};
                \draw (M.center) -- (fr) node [left] {$\vec f_r$};
            }
            \draw [densely dotted, gray] (fr) |- (N) node [pos=.25, left] {\tiny$\lVert \vec F\rVert\cos\theta$} node [pos=.75, above] {\tiny$\lVert \vec F\rVert\sin\theta$};
            \draw (M.center)+(90+\Fangle:\arcr) arc [start angle=90+\Fangle,end angle=90,radius=\arcr] node [above, pos=.5] {\tiny$\theta=\Fangle$};
        \end{scope}
        % Draw gravity force. The code is put outside the rotated
        % scope for simplicity. No need to do any angle calculations. 
        \draw[force,->] (M.center) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\vec P$};
        \draw (M.center)+(-90:\arcr) arc [start angle=-90,end angle=\iangle-90,radius=\arcr] node [right, pos=.5] {\tiny$\alpha=\iangle$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very fancy output!!