# How to draw 90 degree angles in intersection points using tikzpicture environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

Please consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=black,only marks,mark=*}}
\pgfplotsset{holdot/.style={color=red,fill=white,very thick,only marks,mark=*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}  
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        legend pos=outer north east,
        axis lines = center,
        axis equal,
        xticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
        yticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$,
        clip=false,
        legend style={cells={align=left}},
        legend cell align={left}
    ]
    \addplot[thick,samples=80] {-x/abs(x)^(2/3)};    % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144463/152550
    \addplot[thick,samples=80] ({sqrt(16/3)*cos((x) r)}, {sqrt(16)*sin((x) r)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Plot]

I would like to draw a `90` degree angles in the two interception points:

[image: 90 degree angles]

The functions are `y^3 = x` and `x^2/(16/3)+y^2/(16)=1`.

Thanks!

**EDIT.** Thanks to [Ruixi's useful comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457000/how-to-draw-90-degree-angles-in-intersection-points-using-tikzpicture-environmen#comment1149585_457000) for find a mistake in the function `y^3=x`!

Comment: That's an interesting question, +1. Will look at it when I'm back in our burrow unless someone else answered it in between.

Comment: @marmot the others are not? Hahahaha. Ok, enjoy.

Comment: Maybe [this awesome Skillmon's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453602/152550) help?

Comment: I don’t think the first function is `y^3 = x`…

Comment: @RuixiZhang I agree with you. manooooh, do you want your function, which is `y=-3*x/|x|^{2/3}`,  or `y^3=x`?

Comment: @RuixiZhang you are absolutely right, my apologies. There is a symmetry with respect to `y`-axis. Althought it should be `y^3=x`, as you said.

Comment: This question was inspired [by this awesome video](https://youtu.be/sD0NjbwqlYw?t=923), made by an incredible software. Enjoy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a proposal of 2 macros that draw the right angles.

They have 3 mandatory arguments: the point of intersection and the names of the two paths. The optional argument is used to transmit tikz options. I would have liked to group them into a single macro, but I didn't succeed.

They use the `intersections` and `calc` libraries of tikz.

```
% require \usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\newcommand{\rightangleA}[4][]{
\begin{scope}
\path[name path=#2#3#4](#2) circle(6pt);
\path[name intersections={of=#2#3#4 and #3,name=i1}];
\path[name intersections={of=#2#3#4 and #4,name=i2}];
\draw[#1] (i1-1)to($(i1-1)+(i2-1)-(#2)$)to(i2-1)to(#2);
\end{scope}
}
\newcommand{\rightangleB}[4][]{
\begin{scope}
\path[name path=#2#3#4](#2) circle(6pt);
\path[name intersections={of=#2#3#4 and #3,name=i1}];
\path[name intersections={of=#2#3#4 and #4,name=i2}];
\draw[#1] (i1-2)to($(i1-2)+(i2-1)-(#2)$)to(i2-1)to(#2);
\end{scope}
}
```

[image: macro]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=black,only marks,mark=*}}
\pgfplotsset{holdot/.style={color=red,fill=white,very thick,only marks,mark=*}}

\newcommand{\rightangleA}[4][]{
\begin{scope}
\path[name path=#2#3#4](#2) circle(6pt);
\path[name intersections={of=#2#3#4 and #3,name=i1}];
\path[name intersections={of=#2#3#4 and #4,name=i2}];
\draw[#1] (i1-1)to($(i1-1)+(i2-1)-(#2)$)to(i2-1)to(#2);
\end{scope}
}
\newcommand{\rightangleB}[4][]{
\begin{scope}
\path[name path=#2#3#4](#2) circle(6pt);
\path[name intersections={of=#2#3#4 and #3,name=i1}];
\path[name intersections={of=#2#3#4 and #4,name=i2}];
\draw[#1] (i1-2)to($(i1-2)+(i2-1)-(#2)$)to(i2-1)to(#2);
\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}  
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        legend pos=outer north east,
        axis lines = center,
        axis equal,
        xticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
        yticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$,
        clip=false,
        legend style={cells={align=left}},
        legend cell align={left}
    ]
    \addplot[thick,samples=80,name path=A] {-x/abs(x)^(2/3)};    % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144463/152550
    \addplot[thick,samples=80,name path=B] ({sqrt(16/3)*cos((x) r)}, {sqrt(16)*sin((x) r)});
    \path[name intersections={of=A and B,by={c,d}}];% intersections of paths
    \rightangleA{c}{A}{B}
    \rightangleB[blue]{c}{A}{B}
    \rightangleA[fill=red,thick]{d}{A}{B}
    %\rightangleB{d}{A}{B}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think that this is by far the best answer here. Simple and working.

Comment: @marmot Thank you very much, I would like to improve it in order to make a single macro (and not several) that would allow you to choose the cadran where the right angle appears. Is that a good idea? If so, do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: But you already have nice single macros, Do you want to put everything into a single path command? Even if this is possible, I think it will be less clean than what you already have because you need to first draw the auxiliary path (the circle, which is a great trick BTW!), and then compute the intersections. Personally I do not see a real advantage of doing this.

Answer (score 9):

Another math exercise for me! Here you go:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=black,only marks,mark=*}}
\pgfplotsset{holdot/.style={color=red,fill=white,very thick,only marks,mark=*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}  
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        legend pos=outer north east,
        axis lines = center,
        axis equal,
        xticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
        yticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$,
        clip=false,
        legend style={cells={align=left}},
        legend cell align={left}
    ]
    \addplot[thick,samples=80] {(-3)*x/abs(x)*abs(x)^(1/3)};    % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144463/152550
    \addplot[thick,samples=80] ({sqrt(16/3)*cos((x) r)}, {sqrt(16)*sin((x) r)});
    \pgfmathsetmacro\intersectionx{-1.3157310986}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\intersectiony{3.2873325096}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\intersectionangle{%
      atan((-2*\intersectionx/(16/3))/(2*\intersectiony/16))
    }
    \pgfmathsetmacro\cornersidelength{0.3}
    \filldraw (axis cs:\intersectionx,\intersectiony) circle (1pt);
    \draw[thick]
      (axis cs:{\intersectionx
                -\cornersidelength*sin(\intersectionangle)},
               {\intersectiony
                +\cornersidelength*cos(\intersectionangle)}) --
      (axis cs:{\intersectionx
                -\cornersidelength*sin(\intersectionangle)
                +\cornersidelength*cos(\intersectionangle)},
               {\intersectiony
                +\cornersidelength*cos(\intersectionangle)
                +\cornersidelength*sin(\intersectionangle)}) --
      (axis cs:{\intersectionx
                +\cornersidelength*cos(\intersectionangle)},
               {\intersectiony
                +\cornersidelength*sin(\intersectionangle)});
    \filldraw (axis cs:-\intersectionx,-\intersectiony) circle (1pt);
    \draw[thick]
      (axis cs:{-\intersectionx
                +\cornersidelength*cos(\intersectionangle)},
               {-\intersectiony
                +\cornersidelength*sin(\intersectionangle)}) --
      (axis cs:{-\intersectionx
                +\cornersidelength*cos(\intersectionangle)
                +\cornersidelength*sin(\intersectionangle)},
               {-\intersectiony
                +\cornersidelength*sin(\intersectionangle)
                -\cornersidelength*cos(\intersectionangle)}) --
      (axis cs:{-\intersectionx
                +\cornersidelength*sin(\intersectionangle)},
               {-\intersectiony
                -\cornersidelength*cos(\intersectionangle)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: right angles]

---

So what is the math magic behind the drawing? Of course, you would need to figure out the coordinates of the intersections by yourself, which is a drawback of the above solution. Here are the derivations:

[image: derivations]

Comment: Am I in problems if you have to change the function to `y^3=x`? I plot it and there's is no nice display...

Comment: Awesome trick and the code is easy to modify! I have two more functions so I added new macros changing its names, but I cannot deal with `intersectionangle` (now `intersectionanglee`). How did you define that? Now my new ellipse becomes `x^2+y^2/3=1`. I tried with `\pgfmathsetmacro\intersectionanglee{%
      atan((-2*\intersectionxx)/(2*\intersectionyy/3))
    }` but it is not correct. Please see https://imgur.com/a/Xq0mRiZ.

Comment: @manooooh Derivations added.

Answer (score 5):

There are some weird effects when one computes intersections of some paths defined inside an axis outside the axis, so I'm stuck with an ugly solution in which the factors `1.1` and `1.13` are hard coded. If it were not for these effects, one could have a much nicer solution which does not rely on any computations of the user...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
        legend pos=outer north east,
        axis lines = center,
        axis equal,
        xticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
        yticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$,
        clip=false,
        legend style={cells={align=left}},
        legend cell align={left}
    ]
    \addplot[thick,samples=80,name path=A] {(-3)*x/abs(x)^(2/3)};    % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144463/152550
    \addplot[thick,samples=80,name path=B] ({sqrt(16/3)*cos((x) r)}, {sqrt(16)*sin((x) r)});
    \path[name intersections={of=A and B}] (0,0) coordinate (O) (1,0)
    coordinate(X);
   \end{axis}
    \path 
    let \p1=($(X)-(O)$),\p2=($(intersection-1)-(O)$),\n1={\x2/\x1},
    \n2={-1/(pow(abs(\n1),2/3))} in 
    (intersection-1) -- + (-0.3,{-0.3*\n2*1cm/1pt}) coordinate(aux1)
    (intersection-1) -- + ({-0.3*\n2*1cm/1pt},0.3) coordinate(aux2)
    (intersection-1) -- + ({-0.3cm-0.3*\n2*1cm/1pt},{0.3cm-0.3*\n2*1cm/1pt}) coordinate(aux3);
    \path[draw=red] (aux3) -- ($(aux3)+1.13*($(aux2)-(aux3)$)$);
    \path[draw=red] (aux3) -- ($(aux3)+1.1*($(aux1)-(aux3)$)$);
    \path 
    let \p1=($(X)-(O)$),\p2=($(intersection-2)-(O)$),\n1={\x2/\x1},
    \n2={-1/(pow(abs(\n1),2/3))} in 
    (intersection-2) -- + (0.3,{0.3*\n2*1cm/1pt}) coordinate(aux1)
    (intersection-2) -- + ({0.3*\n2*1cm/1pt},-0.3) coordinate(aux2)
    (intersection-2) -- + ({0.3cm+0.3*\n2*1cm/1pt},{-0.3cm+0.3*\n2*1cm/1pt}) coordinate(aux3);
    \path[draw=red] (aux3) -- ($(aux3)+1.13*($(aux2)-(aux3)$)$);
    \path[draw=red] (aux3) -- ($(aux3)+1.1*($(aux1)-(aux3)$)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just noted that there seems something really weird going on with the pgfplotslibrary fillbetween.

Comment: Am I in problems if you have to change the function to `y^3=x`? I plot it and there's is no nice display...

Comment: @manooooh According to what I find [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457012/interactions-between-intersections-fillbetween-and-axis-equal?noredirect=1&lq=1), we are all in trouble. ;-) More seriously, at this point Ruixi's nice answer is clearly superior. (On the other hand, if it were not for these unexpected problems, there would be a nice simple trick that would avoid the necessity to compute things by hand. However, I have no clue how to fix these problems.) In order to plot `y=x^{1/3}`, you only need to drop the factor `3`, i.e. plot `{-x/abs(x)^(2/3)};`.