# How to modify TikZ patterns

Tags: tikz-pgf, stanli

The Task: Draw a ground for a tank.

My solution: Using `TikZ patterns` library (see page 171 of the `TikZ & PGF` [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{stanli}% loads TikZ, see: https://ctan.org/pkg/stanli

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

    % ground
    \draw
      [very thick] (0, 0) -- (5, 0);
    % for comparison
    \support{3}{0, 0};% stanli
    \filldraw         % tikz
      [pattern = north east lines] (1, 0) rectangle (5, -.4);
    % tank
    \draw
      (5, 0)     .. controls (5, 1) and (5.1, 1.1)
                 .. (5.5, 1.1)
      (5.5, 1.4) .. controls (5.1, 1.4) and (5, 1.5)
                 .. (5, 2.5) -- (5, 5)
      (5, 4) -- (0, 4)
      (0, 5) -- (0, 0);
    % atmospheric pressure
    \node at (6, 5) {$p_0$};
    % density
    \node at (1, 3) {$\varrho$};
    % inflow
    \draw
      [->] (-.5, 5.5) .. controls (-.25, 5.5) and (.25, 5.5)
                      .. node[sloped, above] {Zufluss}
           (.5, 4.25);
    % hydrostatic head
    \draw
      (4, 4) -- (4.15, 4.3) -- (3.85, 4.3) -- cycle
      (3.85, 3.9) -- (4.15, 3.9)
      (3.90, 3.8) -- (4.10, 3.8)
      (3.95, 3.7) -- (4.05, 3.7);
    % velocity
    % v_1
    \draw
      [->] (2.5,4) node[above] {1} -- node[sloped, above, at end] {$v_1$} (2.5, 3);
    %v_2
    \draw
      [->] (5.5, 1.25) node[above = 5pt] {2} -- node[above, at end] {$v_2$} (6.5, 1.25);
    % flow line
    \draw
      [dashed] (2.5, 2.9) .. controls (3, 2) and (5, 1.25)
                          .. (5.4, 1.25);
    % coordinate system
    \support{3}{7.5, 1.25};
    \draw
      [->,dashed] (7, 1.25) -- node[sloped, above, at end] {$z$} (7, 2.5);
    % height
    \dimensioning{2}{8, 1.25}{8, 4}{8}[$h$];

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:
[image: result]
Right is the ground drawn by `Tikz`. That isn't nice (my opinion). Can I somehow modify the `north east lines` pattern, so that the ground for the tank looks like a ground drawn by the `stanli` package (for example `\support{3}{coordinates}`). The ground comes with the `stanli` package, if observe strictly, isn't a ground, but I like it and would use it here, but it has fixed length.

An completely different solution, which gives the same result for the ground like done by the `stanli` package (even with different length) is welcome too. Any suggestions?

P. S. Any other optimizations or criticism are welcome too!

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: Your result image has no anti-[aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). If I just compile the ti*k*Z-part with the north east lines to PDF it looks fine and smooth. So maybe the problem is your compile method or the viewer software.

Comment: I agree with @dexteritas and would like to draw your attention to [this cool answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29367/121799) in which flexible north east lines were introduced: you can adjust the distances etc.

Comment: Hello @dexteritas! Thank you for your comment! This is strange. I use Adobe Acrobat Pro DC 15.010.20059.40980 and have on my both computers this aliasing effect, even if I zoom up to 800%.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All I did was to copy the `flexible hatch` pattern from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29367/121799) and to adjust two parameters.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{stanli}% loads TikZ, see: https://ctan.org/pkg/stanli

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29367/121799
\tikzset{
    hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
    hatch distance=10pt,
    hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
    hatch thickness=2pt
}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{flexible hatch}
{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
{\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
{
    \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

    % ground
    \draw
      [very thick] (0, 0) -- (5, 0);
    % for comparison
    \support{3}{0, 0};% stanli
    \filldraw         % tikz
      [pattern=flexible hatch,
        hatch distance=5pt,
        hatch thickness=0.3pt] (1, 0) rectangle (5, -.4);
    % tank
    \draw
      (5, 0)     .. controls (5, 1) and (5.1, 1.1)
                 .. (5.5, 1.1)
      (5.5, 1.4) .. controls (5.1, 1.4) and (5, 1.5)
                 .. (5, 2.5) -- (5, 5)
      (5, 4) -- (0, 4)
      (0, 5) -- (0, 0);
    % atmospheric pressure
    \node at (6, 5) {$p_0$};
    % density
    \node at (1, 3) {$\varrho$};
    % inflow
    \draw
      [->] (-.5, 5.5) .. controls (-.25, 5.5) and (.25, 5.5)
                      .. node[sloped, above] {Zufluss}
           (.5, 4.25);
    % hydrostatic head
    \draw
      (4, 4) -- (4.15, 4.3) -- (3.85, 4.3) -- cycle
      (3.85, 3.9) -- (4.15, 3.9)
      (3.90, 3.8) -- (4.10, 3.8)
      (3.95, 3.7) -- (4.05, 3.7);
    % velocity
    % v_1
    \draw
      [->] (2.5,4) node[above] {1} -- node[sloped, above, at end] {$v_1$} (2.5, 3);
    %v_2
    \draw
      [->] (5.5, 1.25) node[above = 5pt] {2} -- node[above, at end] {$v_2$} (6.5, 1.25);
    % flow line
    \draw
      [dashed] (2.5, 2.9) .. controls (3, 2) and (5, 1.25)
                          .. (5.4, 1.25);
    % coordinate system
    \support{3}{7.5, 1.25};
    \draw
      [->,dashed] (7, 1.25) -- node[sloped, above, at end] {$z$} (7, 2.5);
    % height
    \dimensioning{2}{8, 1.25}{8, 4}{8}[$h$];

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To an ordinary marmot's eye they are almost indistinguishable. Notice that at lower zoom the pattern does indeed look a bit weird on preview and even on acroread, but as @dexteritas points out, these are viewer issues that go away once one zooms in.

Comment: Hellp @marmot! Thank you for your answer! The adviced [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29367/121799) provided many acknowledgement! At least one thing: How can I delete the frame around the `flexible hatch` pattern?

Comment: @Su-47 Instead of `\filldraw` just say `\fill` or `\path` (in this case) n order to only fill put not draw.