# how can we have one \addlegendentry for two superposed sets (a hatched pattern with a orange background)?

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I am writing to ask for your help, please. I would like to add a colour (orange for example) to the background of an initial Pattern (see below). Is there an option to do that: to have a legend that is identical to the new figure? (i.e. with two colours : lines and background)

I use the following code to colour the background of the initial pattern, however I am not able to modify the presentation of the legend. \addlegendentry{Interval 2}

Can you tell me how to get the "interval 2" legend to correspond to the pattern used in the graph?

Many thanks for your time and help. 
Best regards,
Steph

[image: set hatched but not legend]

[modification from this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29359/pgfplots-how-to-fill-the-area-under-a-curve-with-oblique-lines-hatching-as-a)

Code with orange background added :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
    hatch distance=10pt,
    hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
    hatch thickness=2pt
}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{flexible hatch}
{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
{\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
{
    \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}

\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-4,xmax=4,
    xlabel={z},
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    axis on top,
    legend style={legend cell align=right,legend plot pos=right}] 

\addplot[name path=A,color=red,domain=-4:4,samples=100] {1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-x^2/2)};
\addlegendentry{z}

\path[name path=B] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);


\addplot+[draw,pattern=flexible hatch,pattern color=red]
fill between[
    of=A and B,
    soft clip={domain=0:1},
];
\addlegendentry{Interval 1}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% for orange background
\addplot+[ %forget plot,
 fill=orange,%opacity=0.3,
 ]
 fill between[
    of=A and B,
    soft clip={domain=-2:-0.5},
    ];
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\addplot[area legend,pattern=flexible hatch,pattern color=cyan,draw=blue,hatch distance=5pt, hatch thickness=0.5pt]
fill between[
    of=A and B,
    soft clip={domain=-2:-0.5},
];

\addlegendentry{Interval 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw the orange area with the same `\addplot` as the pattern by adding `preaction = {fill = orange}` to its optional arguments and remove the separate `\addplot` for the orange area. This should fix your legend entry.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
    hatch distance=10pt,
    hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
    hatch thickness=2pt
}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{flexible hatch}
{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
{\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
{
    \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}

\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-4,xmax=4,
    xlabel={z},
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    axis on top,
    legend style={legend cell align=right,legend plot pos=right}]

\addplot[name path=A,color=red,domain=-4:4,samples=100] {1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-x^2/2)};
\addlegendentry{z}

\path[name path=B] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);


\addplot+[draw,pattern=flexible hatch,pattern color=red]
fill between[
    of=A and B,
    soft clip={domain=0:1},
];
\addlegendentry{Interval 1}

\addplot[area legend,preaction={fill=orange},pattern=flexible hatch,pattern color=cyan,draw=blue,hatch distance=5pt, hatch thickness=0.5pt]
fill between[
    of=A and B,
    soft clip={domain=-2:-0.5},
];

\addlegendentry{Interval 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Very simple! Thanks, exactly what I want.

Comment: You're welcome, I am happy I could help!

Comment: If this solution works for you, you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark. ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I forget to clicking on the check mark. Done.

Comment: In my version of LaTex (2015?), sometimes I need "\shorthandoff{:}" before the "\addplot" with "soft clip={domain=-2:-0.5}" because if not, sometimes, not always, I have a message error. I must remember it. Very nice, I am very happy. Best regards

Comment: Another thing, I put a \makeatother command, after Jake's code to hatch the pattern for sure it run well everywhere. Am I right? I think that "ça ne mange pas de pain" it's an collaquial French expression to say that does not involve a great risk by doing that, I have got nothing to lose.